# Create a heat map with ggplot to help us highlight the difference between categories

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, colorbrewer

I am examining my current cluster and my instructions are to create a heat map with ggplot. I typed in the required commands and nothing happens and I have installed the RColorBrewer package as well. The instructions also say "The default colors of ggplot need to be changed with the RColorBrewer library. You can use the conda library and the code to launch in the terminal:

conda install -c r r-rcolorbrewer"

This command doesnt work when I type it and I followed teh conda library at "https://anaconda.org/r/r-rcolorbrewer" and still nothing. What am I missing?
Below are screenshots of instructions and then the commands I typed in that did nothing. [image]

[image]
This is what I performed and nothing happened.

Comment: My guess is you have to explicitly open a graphics device, or save the image to a path, since you're running from command line. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502217/17303805) may be relevant. You could instead use an IDE like RStudio or [rstudio.cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/), in which case the image would automatically appear.

Comment: Also have a look at ["Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?,"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805) and please copy and paste your code next time instead.

Comment: As others have said, its better to provide the code directly into your question next time rather than a screenshot.